# eve 0.8 `allow_unknown` in nested dict field

Tags: python, validation, eve, cerberus

We developed a API using Eve 0.7 that used [`allow_unknown` on a nested dict field](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/latest/usage.html#allowing-the-unknown).  This field worked as expected according to the cerberus documentation.

We are now upgrading to Eve 0.8 and our endpoints no longer respect the `allow_unknown` parameter in nested dicts.

#### Example

*settings.py*

```
DOMAIN = {
    'endpoint': {
        'schema': {
            'data': {
                'type': 'dict',
                'allow_unknown': True,
                'schema': {
                    'prop': {'type': 'string'}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
```

*app.py*

```
from eve import Eve

app = Eve()
app.run(debug=True)
```

### Test

- Run the app by running: `$ python app.py`
- Test the endpoint with curl:

Pass

```
$ curl -d '{"data": {"prop": "test prop"}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint
{"_updated": "Fri, 08 Jun 2018 19:43:11 GMT", "_created": "Fri, 08 Jun 2018 19:43:11 GMT", "_etag": "e04dd19a6e13c74ccdb5561722bb001b0f5dff28", "_id": "5b1adc4f198a2527650320a4", "_links": {"self": {"title": "Endpoint", "href": "endpoint/5b1adc4f198a2527650320a4"}}, "_status": "OK"}
```

Fail (would expect this to pass)

```
$ curl -d '{"data": {"prop": "test prop", "test": 2}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint
{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"data": {"test": "unknown field"}}, "_error": {"code": 422, "message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an actual issue, thanks for reporting it. It is fixed with v0.8.1.dev0.

- [v0.8.1 Changelog](http://python-eve.org/changelog.html#version-0-8-1)
- [Actual commit](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/commit/0360bf90340fc3ae5f0230913e6f171add04caa6)

Thanks for reporting it!